# Jar generated via warbler is not able to open bundled Poltergeist gem

Tags: executable-jar, poltergeist, warbler

I have created a plugin with jruby-1.7.9 and added below gems inside my gemspec

```
spec.add_dependency 'phantomjs'
spec.add_dependency 'capybara'
spec.add_dependency 'poltergeist'
```

Created JAR for this plugin using Warbler(version:1.4.4).
This JAR consist of below code :

```
require 'capybara'

module Zerp
  class Chatter
    def say_hello
      Capybara.visit 'http://google.com'
      puts "#{Capybara.page.text}"
    end
  end
end
```

The JAR is executing successfully while running it inside the plugin.

Now I copied JAR at another location and tried to run it from there. Then I'm getting below error when JAR is executing first line of the code(visit google home page) :

```
Can't open '/home/ndashore/nikhil/zerp.jar!/gems/poltergeist-1.5.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/main.js'
```

Have checked file location, the file exist there and I'm able to open it.

Also have tried to use other Gem (tried with phantomjs). It works properly and do the stuff.

Please help me to use poltergeist as bundled gem.